# Unable to read excel file with openpyxl

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I am trying to open an excel archive but i couldn't do it:

```
import openpyxl
doc = openpyxl.load_workbook ("C:/Users/administra/Datos_Campo_El_Mirador.xlsx")
```

Output: `ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence`

I try again changing ashes

```
import openpyxl
doc = openpyxl.load_workbook ("C:/Users/administra/Datos_Campo_El_Mirador.xlsx")
```

The same error `(ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence)`

Thank you very much

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace, and a reproducible example. Without this, we cannot help you. For reference, please read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: import openpyxl wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/administra/Datos_Campo_El_Mirador.xlsx')type(wb) Traceback (most recent call last):  File "<ipython-input-83-a9565529828b>", line 2, in <module> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/administra Datos_Campo_El_Mirador.xlsx') File "C:\Users\administra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()File "C:\Users\administra\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\chart\reader.py", line 26, in read_chart chart.idx_base = min(s.idx for s in chart.series) ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: Is your file empty? Maybe you should report that to openpyxl